# Salesforce Developer Console Bug

Tags: force.com, developer-console

- This is my first time to use SF as this platform is quite interesting
  now. However, I tried to use `developer console > create apex class`
  and when saving, it is always stuck on that, see

  [image]
- Is this something a bug? I tried to create a new account thinking but
  the issue lies on my account. Furthermore, I have tested it with
  different browser but no luck.
- Also, the log is not working as it should be. I still need to close
  the developer to view the logs as there is no logs showing and is not
  realtime. Is this how it suppose to work? If not, can you please help
  me on how to make the developer console work?

I am still a newbie on this field so any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You can try to create new workspace

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the Developer console, It has come along way in the past 2 years but can still be flaky at best. 
I would recommend Sublime with Mavensmate plug in.
As for debug logs, You would not be able to debug what you are doing in dev console.